# SessionNotCreatedException after updating firefox, geckodriver and Selenium Webdrivers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I've updated all the below to the latest versions:

geckodriver (v0.33.0)
FireFox (115.0)
Selenium Webdrivers (4.10.0)

When trying to run a Selenium test via JUnit I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Reading from previous instances it appears to be a compatibility issue but I can't see why this would be happening if I've got latest versions of everything.

My code:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("newProfile");
    myprofile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
    

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setCapability("firefox_binary", "c:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    options.setProfile(myprofile);
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    
    driver.get(websiteURL);
```

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: Updated with code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Release date of geckodriver (v0.33.0) is `2023-04-03`, but the FireFox (115.0) is `2023-07-04` --> I don't think these are compatible. Try with lower version of firefox.

Comment: No luck. I uninstalled FF 115 and installed 111. Stopped the auto update to prevent new version being installed. Getting the same issue

Comment: Don't know much but with selenium 4.10, it has a built-in driver manager that will download the driver based on the version of installed browser, just need to define which browser you want. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/

Comment: Thanks @lucas-nguyen-17. I resolved this by changing the firefox to 32bit and using the 32bit geckodrivers. This seems to work